# Driving Subarus without coolant

Tags: cooling-system, subaru, overheating

Years ago I decided to drive a Brat from Wyoming to Indiana. It started losing coolant climbing the Bighorns. I kept on driving. By the time I left Wyoming their was no coolant in the system. It didn't seem to effect the performance. l finished the trip and drove it for a month or two before I found some heads, had them rebuilt and installed them. It never seemed to suffer any adverse effects.

Will any of the newer Subarus do that? I just bought a 1999 Subaru Legacy 2.5.  Something tells me I would be pushing the limits to try running it out of coolant.

Comment: Hi! Do you have a specific mechanical problem that you're trying to solve? If,instead, you'd like to have an open-ended discussion with plenty of car nerds, please feel free to stop by the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  @Bill I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

It's not wise to drive any car with no coolant running through the engine. It could cause a multitude of problems ranging from overheating, water pump failure, to a cracked block.